# Is that correct to say "It is so snowy today. I haven't seen to much snow here before."?

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, spoken-english

Canada was so snowy today and I saw too much snow and I used a sentence about that and I wasn't sure if it was true or not.

> It is so snowy today. I haven't seen to much snow here before.

I'm oftenly confusing about how to use perfect tenses. Can I say that or what's the better sentence for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  The more natural way to say it would be:

> It's so snowy today.  I haven't seen *this* much snow here before.

Or, a little more natural:

> I've never seen this much snow here.

Or, alternately.

> I've never seen it snow this much here.

In this case the use of the present perfect indicates a *life experience* and not an ongoing condition.  It's similar to the use of the perfect in these examples:

> I have never traveled outside of the United States.
>
> I have eaten insects.
>
> I have read that book.

Comment: Thank you so much! So if I was seeing second time, how would I say with Present Perfect Continuous tense? "I've been seeing a snow this much here at the second time" Is that correct?

Comment: "This is the second time I've seen it snow this much"

Answer (score 0):

"I haven't seen *so* much snow" is perfectly idiomatic, and slightly less formal than "this much".

"too" (not "to") would work as well. "I haven't seen too much snow yet" means you have seen only a moderate amount, probably suggesting that you haven't seen as much as you might have expected.